# How to exclude rows from a groupby operation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a groupby operation using the `attribute` column but I want to exclude the `desc_type 1 and 2` that will be used to calculate total discount inside each attrib.

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID':[10,10,10,20,30,30],'attribute':['attrib_1','desc_type1','desc_type2','attrib_1','attrib_2','desc_type1'],'value':[100,0,0,100,30,0],'discount':[0,6,2,0,0,13.3]})
```

output:

```
ID       attribute       value      discount
10       attrib_1        100          0
10       desc_type1       0           6
10       desc_type2       0           2
20       attrib_1         100         0
30       attrib_2         30          0
30       desc_type1       0           13.3
```

I want to groupby this dataframe by `attribute` but excluding the `desc_type1 and desc_type2`.

The desired output:

```
attribute     ID_count    value_sum   discount_sum
attrib_1         2          200          8
attrib_2         1          30          13.3
```

explanations:

`attrib_1` has **discount_sum=8**  because **ID 30** that belongs to `attrib_1`has two desc_type

`attrib_2` has **discount_sum=13.3**  because **ID 10** has one desc_type

`ID=20` has no discounts types.

What I did so far:

```
df.groupby('attribute').agg({'ID':'count','value':'sum','discount':'sum'})
```

But the line above does not exclude the `desc_type 1 and 2` from the groupby

Important:  an ID may have a discount or not.

link to the realdataset: [realdataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13i3ArvBXj2VBRhquAvoUX5H7puFRODNy/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106219169070264712406&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the attributes per ID, then `groupby.agg`:

```
m = df['attribute'].str.startswith('desc_type')
group = df['attribute'].mask(m).groupby(df['ID']).ffill()

out = (df
 .groupby(group, as_index=False)
 .agg(**{'ID_count': ('ID', 'nunique'),
         'value_sum': ('value', 'sum'),
         'discount_sum': ('discount', 'sum')
        })
)
```

output:

```
   ID_count  value_sum  discount_sum
0         2        200           8.0
1         1         30          13.3
```

Comment: Use `.groupby(group).agg(...).reset_index()`

Comment: your answer really solved the question problem but I dont know why it dosen't sum the discount values on my real dataset...weird.  Is there any way I can share my dataset with you?

Comment: I added the link to the realdataset.  IF you don't have time, no worries, you already helped alot.  Huge thanks

Comment: last comment: it works on my realdataset but only if I replace `ffill()` by `bfill()`

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think this helps :

```
df.loc[(df['attribute'] != 'desc_type1') &( df['attribute'] != 'desc_type2')].groupby('attribute').agg({'ID':'count','value':'sum','discount':'sum'})
```

Output :

```
    ID  value   discount
attribute           
attrib_1    2   200 0.0
attrib_2    1   30  0.0
```